# How to prevent spamming bullets in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In my game, there is a problem with bullet spamming, because the player can shoot a lot of bullets in a short time. How can I prevent the player to do that? Should I use a clock? And how can I use the clock? Here it is some code:

```
class Player (Obj):
    def command (self, shoot):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        self.shoot = shoot       
        if keys[shoot]:
            self.Shoot()
    def Shoot(self):   
        global prts
        prts.append (Ammo(player.x, player.y, prt_img ))
        print (prts)

while True:
    window.fill(WHITE)
    player.blit()
    player.command(pg.K_SPACE)
    for ammo in prts:
        ammo.blit()
        ammo.Move(0.5)
        ammo.BordCheck()
    pg.display.update()
```

[Here it is an image of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awcnG.png)

*Sorry for any mistakes*

Comment: One way you could limit the amounts of shots, is to remove the entry for the bullet in `prts` if it ever leaves the screen, and then just check `len(prts)` when you spawn the bullets to see if you should append a new bullet or not depending on the current "traveling" bullets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pygame by default will trigger the key pressed event as fast as your computer can handle it (meaning the better the computer, the faster you will shoot). This has been a common issue in old video games that were only tested on one computer.

Adding a 'clock' is a good way of fixing the problem. For example if you want the player to shoot no faster than a bullet every half a second, you can get the current time when he shoots and then on the next shoot you check the time, if less than 1/2 second has passed you don t shoot, else you shoot and update the time with the time of the new bullet.

For more optimization, you might even want to completely block the keyboard input from firing a 'shooting key pressed' event while the player cannot shoot but that is a minor optimization that shouldn t be necessary in a small game.

To manipulate time in python, you can use the time and datetime default modules. I often suggest using [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you have a lot of times and dates to manipulate as it is a bit simpler I think.

Here is an example comparing seconds using datetime :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from datetime import datetime

t1 = datetime.strptime("Feb 12 08:02:34 2015", "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
t2 = datetime.strptime("Feb 12 08:02:32 2015", "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

difference = t1 - t2

print(difference.seconds) # 2, in this case
```

Does this solve your problem ?